# Запись в BLOB поле и извечение из него картинки

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Нужно записать картинку из файла в BLOB поле и обратно. Есть примеры на C#, но все они не работают под C++/CLI. Прошу помочь сделать это под C++. Проблема скорее в синтаксисе. Может у кого-то есть примеры работы или книги с записью BLOB именно в visual C++/CLI.

Ms SQL 2008 и Visual c++/cli.

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что в data (byte[]) - ваши данные для записи в базу на C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Data) VALUES(@Data)", connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary, data.Length).Value = data;

connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

На С++/CLI:

```
SqlCommand* cmd  = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Data) VALUES(@Data)", connection);

(cmd->Parameters->Add("@Data", SqlDbType::Binary, data->Length))->Value = data;

connection->Open();
cmd->ExecuteNonQuery();
connection->Close();
```

P.S. Не проверял. Вообще в MSDN есть примеры для С++/CLI. Нужно выбрать .NET 1.1 на странице справки и они будут доступны.

Comment: Этот код я пробовал "перевести" на c++/cli, но увы ничего из этого не вышло. Компилятор не понимает ни создания Byte, ни массива, пишет что мол тип unsigned char.
 
    
 FileStream *fs = new FileStream(SourceFilePath, FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read);
 int size = Convert::ToInt32(fs->Length);
 Byte b[] = __gc new  Byte[size];  
 fs->Read(b, 0, size);
 fs->Close();